# Cannot apply Flyway migration for a PostgreSQL table

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

In my Java app, I have the following migration file:

```
-- code omitted for brevity 

create table if not exists demo_table
(
    id                  bigint       not null,
    "company"           varchar(50)  not null,
    "name"              varchar(50)  not null
    );

create unique index if not exists demo_table_uuid_company_key
    on demo_table (uuid, "company");
    
create index if not exists demo_table_name_company_key
    on demo_table ("name", "company");
```

Although I can run the `sql` part part part or at a time on PostgreSQL query window, when running my Java app, it throws the following error:

*"Unable to create index (name, company) on table demo_table: database column 'name' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)"*

I tried many thing e.g. removing the related migration row from `flyway_schema_history` table, delete indexes on `demo_table`, etc. But still the same error. If I try to remove double quotes ("") from `name`, it gives checksum error. So, as the `name` is reserve word, I use with double quotes. How can I fix it?

On the other hand, I am not sure if I should change these parameters on `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    enabled: true

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

Comment: Does anybody else using Flyway migration or PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Some minor issues with the script:
Missing comma on first column of create.
This column is also called `id` but the index references `uuid`.

Resolving this allowed the script to work perfectly for me (with the quotes as you have them)

If you make these changes and get a checksum error, please run `flyway repair`

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. Actually I just missed the comma in the question, but it is present in the code. On the other hand, how can I run the flyway script?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the flyway table records with

```
delete from flyway_schema_history;
```